# Is ReLU a non-linear activation function?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, math, activation-functions, relu

According to [this blog post](https://www.deeplearning-academy.com/p/ai-wiki-activation-functions)

> The purpose of an activation function is to add some kind of non-linear property to the function

The sigmoid is typically used as an activation function of a unit of a neural network in order to introduce non-linearity.

Is ReLU a non-linear activation function? And why? If not, then why is it used as an activation function of neural networks?

Answer (score 3):

## ReLU is non-linear by definition

> In calculus and related areas, a [linear function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_function) is a function whose graph is a straight line, that is a polynomial function of degree one or zero.

Since the graph of the ReLU function $f(x) = \max(0,x)$ is not a straight line (equivalently, it cannot be expressed in the form $f(x) = mx + c$), by definition it is not linear.

## ReLU *is* piecewise linear

ReLU *is* [piecewise linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise_linear_function) on the bounds $(-\inf,0]$ and $[0,\inf)$:

$$
f(x) = \max(0,x) = \begin{cases}
               0               & x \le 0\\
               x               & x \gt 0\\
       \end{cases}
$$

But this is still non-linear on the entire domain:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Short Answer:** Yes

**Visually:**

[image]

if you see the image from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_function), it shown that ReLU (the blue line) is non-Linear (the line is not straight, it turns in 0). You can also check "visual" definition of linear function in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_function):

> "In calculus and related areas, a linear function is a function whose graph is a straight line"

**Mathematically:**

Linear function of one variable can be defined as:

$ f(x) = ax + b $

If you plot that function in 2D, it will give you a straight line. Then, the form of linear function with multi variables:

$ f(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n) = a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + ... + a_nx_n + b $

If you again plot that function in the correct dimension it also give you a straight line. And if you that function carefully, it similar with calculation that happen in a neuron. That's why neuron addition and multiplication is a linear function:

$ f(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n) = w_1x_1 + w_2x_2 + ... + w_nx_n + b $

Adding more layer of linear functions doesn't make the function become "complex" for example, if you have $f(x)$ like below and then you put another layer of linear function $g(x)$ on top of it:

$f(x) = ax + b$

$g(x) = cf(x) + d = cax + cb + d$

as the neural network is trained to find the value of $a,b,c,d$, we can group the constant from the formula above, and then rewrite to:

$h(x) = mx + n$

with $m=ca$ and $n=cb+d$. So without non-linear function the layer of neural network is useless, it only give you another "simple" linear function

ReLU formula is a $f(x)=max(0,x)$, it produces non-linearity as you can't write to linear function format. Using this function will give you "complexity" when you add more layer on top of it.